# How does for nested loop in python behave when range is the same for both outer and nested loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Can you explain how the nested *for* loop behaves in figure 1?

```
x = 4
for j in range(x)
   for i in range(x)
       print(i)
       x = 2
```

Fig.1

Results

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
0
1
0
1
```

I know the first 4 integers printed ( 0 - 3) are a result of the code
      for j in range(x): code but why are the the following also printed?

```
0
1
0
1
0
1
```

The code

```
x = 4
for j in range(x):
    print(i)
    x = 5
```

Prints

```
0
1
2
3
```

Thus showing that changing the value x inside the *for* loop has no impact on the number of iterations. The arguments in the *range* function are evaluated just before the first iteration of the loop, and not reevaluated for subsequent iterations.

Why then does x change to 2 for the nested loop in figure 1?

Another similar program:

```
num_list = [1, 2, 3]
alpha_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for number in num_list:
    print(number)
    for letter in alpha_list:
        print(letter)
```

Outputs

```
1 #outer loop
a #nested loop
b #nested loop
c #nested loop
2 #outer loop
a #nested loop
b #nested loop
c #nested loop
3 #outer loop
a #nested loop
b #nested loop
c #nested loop
```

So I would expect figure 1's output to be:

```
0 #outer loop
0 #Nested loop
1 #Nested loop
2 #Nested loop
3 #Nested loop
1 #outer loop
0 #Nested loop
1 #Nested loop
2 #Nested loop
3 #Nested loop
2 #outer loop
0 #Nested loop
1 #Nested loop
2 #Nested loop
3 #Nested loop
3 #outer loop
0 #Nested loop
1 #Nested loop
2 #Nested loop
3 #Nested loop
```

Additional Info
Python 3.5 in Spyder

Answer (score 0):

> Thus showing that changing the value x inside the for loop has no
>   impact on the number of iterations. The arguments in the range
>   function are evaluated just before the first iteration of the loop,
>   and not reevaluated for subsequent iterations.
>
> Why then does x change to 2 for the nested loop in figure 1?

Not exactly. In your first example, with the nested for-loop, it does have an impact on the number of iterations. It's true that once a `range` object is constructed, making changes to any of the variables you used to construct it will have no effect on the `range` object - however, in the nested loop, you aren't just creating two `range` objects. You are creating one for the outer loop, and then a new `range` object for the inner for-loop for each iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value of `x` inside your second `if`-statement.

Your first `if` let's you run the second `if` 4 times. After printing `0 1 2 3`once, your `x` is set to 2, giving you another 3 times `0 1`.

As the first `if`-`range` iterator is already running, the changing x isn't influenced. Better don't change the variable, you are looping though.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the scope of the variables. The x that is inside the inner 'for' loop with variable 'i' is given preference within the inner 'for' loop. This variable x is not visible outside the inner 'for' loop and so when you reference x in the outer 'for' loop (with variable 'j'), it references the global value of 4 and not 2.

Hope that makes sense.

Just my 2 cents -- This is not a very good coding practice, try to avoid (if possible) and use distinct variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Add some debug code to see what's going on to make it clearer

```py
    loops = 1
    x = 4
    for j in range(x):
        print(f'outer: j={j}, x={x}')
        for i in range(x):
           print(f'inner: j={j}, i={i}, x={x}')
           print(i)
           x = 2
           print(f'total loops {loops}')
           loops += 1
```

Output:

```
    outer: j=0, x=4
    inner: j=0, i=0, x=4
    0
    total loops 1
    inner: j=0, i=1, x=2
    1
    total loops 2
    inner: j=0, i=2, x=2
    2
    total loops 3
    inner: j=0, i=3, x=2
    3
    total loops 4
    outer: j=1, x=2
    inner: j=1, i=0, x=2
    0
    total loops 5
    inner: j=1, i=1, x=2
    1
    total loops 6
    outer: j=2, x=2
    inner: j=2, i=0, x=2
    0
    total loops 7
    inner: j=2, i=1, x=2
    1
    total loops 8
    outer: j=3, x=2
    inner: j=3, i=0, x=2
    0
    total loops 9
    inner: j=3, i=1, x=2
    1
    total loops 10
```

It's easy to see that setting `x` once the range is constructed has no affect on the number of outer loop iterations but does change the number of inner loop iterations.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here][1]

```
x = 4
for j in range(x):
    print(i)
    x = 5
```

output

```
0
1
2
3
```

Notice that the program above raise the question whether the value of x affects the number of iterations. It does not. The arguments to the `range` function in the line with `for` **are evaluated just before the first iteration**

So:

```
x = 4
for j in range(x)
   for i in range(x)
       print(i)
       x = 2
#Outputs
0   #j=0,
1   #j=0 
2    #j=0 
3    #j=0 
0    
1
0
1
0
1
```

This is because the `range` function in the outer loop is evaluated only once but the `range` function in the inner loop is evaluated each time the inner `for` statment is reached.

**Note:** for the outer loop the range is evaluated before the first iteration and the first iteration the inner `for` loop  x=4. At the end of the first iteration of the outer `for` loop  the inner `for` loop x =2 as the inner loop cannot see the initial x value.

Here is a flow chart that I thought helped me understand

https://www.programtopia.net/sites/default/files/nested%20for_1.png

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code could explain it.

Your first code is identical to this:

```py
x = 4
gen1 = range(x)  # effectively equal to range(4)

for j in gen1:
   gen2 = range(x)  # For the first time, this is equal to range(4).
                    # And for the following three times, this is equal to range(2).
   for i in gen2:
       print(i)
       x = 2
```

Note that `range(x)` creates and returns a *generator* object which is not altered by changing `x` afterwards. But you are creating a whole new generator object on the line `gen2 = range(x)` everytime, with a new value of `x`.